# Issue with functions as props for components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a type of button I use throughout my application, an example of which is this: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click.prevent="search">Search</button>`. Although the savings in code characters are small, it struck me as worthwhile to create a little component for this, Btn. I could use this thus: `<btn :action="search">Search</btn>`. All well and good.

But I have a problem when I want to use one of Vue's internal special variables as an argument in the function. For example, `<btn :action="removeSelected(index,$event)">X</btn>`. The 'removeSelected' function needs to be passed the event as the second parameter. It's not valid as an argument in the function passed as a prop in a component, though. I get the error message: "[Vue warn]: Property or method "$event" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render." Is there any way round this?

Comment: And this doesn't work? `<btn @click="removeSelected(index)">X</btn>`

Comment: Well, yes, but what I am trying to do here is have an action prop which is used within the Btn component thus: `@click.prevent="action"`. Probably futile, though, as it's not actually capturing the event.

Comment: This is event binding syntax: `@click="hadler"`, this is just attribute binding syntax `:attr="value"`.

Comment: I know. That is what I have in my Btn component - 'action' is the function passed in via a prop. The issue is with the $event variable.

Comment: You can't obtain event from attribute. Try `<btn :action="removeSelected(index)">X</btn>`, without event.

Comment: Yes, that works, but the point of this question was about the $event variable. Without the ability to get hold of that, I cannot usefully use my component in place of a native <button> construct.

Comment: Try `:action="($event) => removeSelected(index, $event)"`. Here is [an example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/bYLYVb?editors=1010).

Comment: Yes, that does it, thanks. I knew it must be possible, somehow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that you want to pass a function to the child component that will receive the `$event` parameter (which all event handlers receive by default) as well as passing a parameter defined in the parent. In order to do that, you can define a function inside the `action` parameter itself.

```
:action="($event) => removeSelected(index, $event)"
```

This defines a function that receives `$event` as a parameter that calles the `removeSelected` method with the capture index and passes along the event.

[Working example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/bYLYVb?editors=1010).